# Python selenium web scraping - empty strings during web scraping

Tags: python, function, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**When I call my function ScrapeTech(), I am presented with empty strings as the output. **

```
watchlist = {"amzn", "googl", "A", "v", "AA"}

def ScrapeTech():
    PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

    for stock in watchlist:
        driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/" + stock + "/technicals/")

        driver.implicitly_wait(20)

        lastprice = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="js-category-content"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/span[1]')

        change = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="js-category-content"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]')

        RSI = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="technicals-root"]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]')

        SMA50 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="technicals-root"]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]')

        SMA100 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="technicals-root"]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[2]')

        SMA200 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="technicals-root"]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[13]/td[2]')

        message = f"{stock}: {lastprice.text}, {change.text}, RSI: {RSI.text}, SMA50: {SMA50.text}, SMA100: {SMA100.text}, SMA200: {SMA200.text}"

        print(message)

    driver.quit()
```

```
**output: amzn: 100.34, +4.14
+4.30%, RSI: 61.00, SMA50: 96.22, SMA100: 95.09, SMA200: 108.50
A: , , RSI: 36.02, SMA50: 148.77, SMA100: 147.85, SMA200: 137.29
AA: , , RSI: 33.24, SMA50: 49.93, SMA100: 47.35, SMA200: 47.28
v: , , RSI: 38.17, SMA50: 223.10, SMA100: 214.90, SMA200: 207.68
googl: , , RSI: 62.82, SMA50: 94.54, SMA100: 94.13, SMA200: 101.88**
```

I have tried:

- repasted XPATH
- used implicity wait method

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! you need to use explicitly wait to let the webpage load before going to the next stock in the for loop.

here is the revised version of the code.:

```
for stock in watchlist:
    driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/" + stock + "/technicals/")

    # Wait for the last price element to be visible before scraping
    last_price = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                          '//*[@id="js-category-content"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/span[1]')))

    # Wait for the change element to be visible before scraping
    change = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="js-category-content"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]')))

    # Wait for the RSI element to be visible before scraping
    RSI = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="technicals-root"]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]')))

    # Wait for the SMA50 element to be visible before scraping
    SMA50 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="technicals-root"]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]')))

    # Wait for the SMA100 element to be visible before scraping
    SMA100 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="technicals-root"]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[2]')))

    # Wait for the SMA200 element to be visible before scraping
    SMA200 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="technicals-root"]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[13]/td[2]')))

    message = f"{stock}: {last_price.text}, {change.text}, RSI: {RSI.text}, SMA50: {SMA50.text}, SMA100: {SMA100.text}, SMA200: {SMA200.text}"

    print(message)

driver.quit()
```

also use:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```